# Wpf Binding Text property of TextBlock from styles

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a datagrid that include `GridCell` style template. I write this style template for that:

```
<Style x:Key="SfDataGridGridCell" TargetType="syncfusion:GridCell">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="IRANSansMobile(FaNum) Light"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11.5"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="syncfusion:GridCell">
                            <Border BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                <Grid>
                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ???}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

             </Style>
```

I want to apply this style for all `DataGrid`'s cells. How can I Binding values that have been marked from xaml or code?

Comment: The binding path will be same for all grid cells or not? Anyway i dont think its a good idea to have a hardcoded binding path in a style but it is possible of course.

Comment: @LukášKoten no It's path is different. What is solution? I need wordwrap and just it's happened in controlTemplate based on syncfusion documents.

Comment: If I undersand correctly you want to change the template for all GridCells? If so I think that in SfDataGridGridCell's template you should have <ContentPresenter/> instead of a TextBlock. The TextBlock can be defined in CellTemplate's DataTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you need is [ContentPresenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter?view=netframework-4.7.2).
If so, you can use ContentPresenter instead of TextBlock.

```xml
<Grid>
    <!--<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ???}"/>-->
    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
</Grid>
```

Please refer to here for how to apply styles to TextBlock in ContentPresenter.
[Applying style resources to ContentPresenter text](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/412b1747-60e9-4b9a-8f8f-bd56f3aff875/applying-style-resources-to-contentpresenter-text?forum=wpf)

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you cannot replace just the path of the binding but reuse the rest of the template. XAML has no support for doing this.

What you could do instead is to create the several styles programmatically, one for each column, using the [XamlReader.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2) method. Then you can simply replace the binding path in the string that you pass to the method.